# How do I prevent blocking the UI due to fast-changing properties during IO operations?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, io

I'm working on an application that at some point deletes a folder. To display a progress to the user, I utilize a `ProgressBar` in the View. Therefore I have two properties on my ViewModel `double SetupProgress` and `double SetupProgressMax`. I compile a list of all files contained in the folder to be deleted and everytime after a file has been deleted successfully, I update the property `SetupProgress`. I don't know the number of files to be deleted beforehand.

My code (condensed to the important parts):

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public double SetupProgress
    {
        get; set; // Notifies about changes
    }

    public double SetupProgressMax
    {
        get; set; // Notifies about changes
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteFiles(IList<string> filesToBeDeleted)
    {
        bool success = true;
        SetupProgressMax = filesToBeDeleted.Count;

        foreach (string filePath in filesToBeDeleted)
        {
            success = success && await IOHelper.TryDeleteFile(filePath);

            if (success)
            {
                // Report that one item has been processed.
                _OnProgressChanged(); 
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return success;
    }

    public void _OnProgressChanged()
    {
        // SetupProgress is the VM property bound by the ProgressBar
        SetupProgress++;
    }
}

public static class IOHelper
{
    public static async Task<bool> TryDeleteFile(string filePath, int tries = 3)
    {
        while (tries > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
                if (fi.IsReadOnly)
                {
                    fi.IsReadOnly = false;
                }
                fi.Delete();
                return true;
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tries--;
                if (tries == 0)
                {
                    // Log error
                }
                else
                {
                    // Log warning
                }
                await Task.Delay(50);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

My problem is that while the files are being deleted, the UI thread completely blocks and will only be updated after the operation finished (all files have been deleted).

### Questions

1. What could be the reason that the UI process is blocking?
2. How can I circumvent this?

---

**UPDATE:** Removed the solutions I've tested before posting the question since they didn't work and couldn't even fix the root of the problem.

Comment: Your issue is this `TryDeleteFile` because `fi.Delete();` is a blocking call and isn't asynchronous... Look at doing `await Task.Run` as IMHO is about as close as you are going to get.

Comment: I've not posted the whole `TryDeleteFile` method. It's actually trying to delete a given file for a given number of tries with a 50 ms delay in between the tries. I'll update the code in the question.

Comment: Now that I've learned that my proposed solutions could not solve my problem, should I remove them to make the question shorter and therefore clearer?

Comment: That would be good if they are not relevant, it does help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `TryDeleteFile` is being executed in the UI thread. Given its current implementation, it's not an asynchronous method and shouldn't return a `Task` but a `bool`:

```
public static bool TryDeleteFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
        if (fi.IsReadOnly)
        {
            fi.IsReadOnly = false;
        }
        fi.Delete();
        return true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log Exception
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `await` keyword is completely unnecessary since the method lacks any `await` operations.

You could call the synchronous method on a background thread in your view model using `Task.Run`:

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteFiles(IList<string> filesToBeDeleted)
{
    ...
    foreach (string filePath in filesToBeDeleted)
    {
        success = success && await Task.Run(() => IOHelper.TryDeleteFile(filePath));
        ...
    }
    return success;
}
```

Note that exposing a method that is truly synchronous using an asynchronous API is considered a bad practice. Please refer to [Stephen Toub's blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) for more information.

Comment: I have updated the code in the question to include my actual implementation of `TryDeleteFile`. According to your answer I changed the `await Task.Delay(50)` in the method to `Thread.Sleep(50)` and incorporated the changes you proposed. Works like a charm, now. So smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TryDeleteFile(string filePath)` method lacks *await* operators, this will run synchronously.

<s>You can wrap synchronous code into asynchronous call, the easier methods is to use `Task.Run`</s>

**EDIT**

There is no native function to perform file deletion asynchronously. However, by using `FileStream`, an asynchronous file deletion can still be performed.

```
public static bool TryDeleteFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        var fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
        if (fi.IsReadOnly) fi.IsReadOnly = false;

        using (new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Delete, 1,
            FileOptions.DeleteOnClose | FileOptions.Asynchronous))
        {
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
                // Log Exception
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
await Task.Run(() => TryDeleteFile(filePath));
```

Comment: Exposing a method that is truly synchronous using an asynchronous API is considered a bad practice: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/. The `TryDeleteFile` method should not return a `Task<bool>` and call `Task.Run`. It's the responsibility of the view model to "offload" the work from the UI thread.

Comment: I haven't posted the whole method, since I thought it wouldn't be this important. But obviously it's no good practice to have a purely synchronous operation in a try block and the only async portion of it in the catch block...